# How to use a SUM formula using an input from another sheet with an address function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to `SUM` every number in a range on a different sheet. This range is dictated by an employee number, as well as the year; it changes for each employee and it also changes every year.

So I need the `sum` function to work like this:

```
​=sum(first cell:second cell)
```

With the cells being variable with each employee.

I had used the `ADDRESS` function to obtain the cell values, but it put the sheet name between apostrophes, e.g. ​`'sheetx!'!A1` , which I thought caused the `sum` function to return an error.

To test this, I made a test `SUM` function using input from the `CELL` function, which returns the sheet value without apostrophes (e.g. ​`sheetx!A1`​). I still got an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: filter did not seem to work for me, but the index and indirect combo worked like a charm

Comment: Why you are trying to use `CELL()` function. Why not `Filter()` then `SUM()` function.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**plain text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to the question. Adding such "markdown tables" greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions like `INDEX`, `OFFSET`,`INDIRECT` return the value as well as the range reference. So, you could use something like

```
=SUM(
  INDEX(Sheetx!A:A,1,1)
  :
  INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,2,1,1,"Sheetx"))
)
```

Note however, `INDEX` and `OFFSET` are preferred over `INDIRECT` as string ranges are better avoided to help internal optimization of spreadsheet.

Comment: If you want a exact formula, share data as text.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Harun24hr, try with the following:

```
=SUM(
  FILTER(
    FILTER( history_earnings!1:1000, history_earnings!A:A=B2 ),
    MATCH( COLUMN( history_earnings!1:1000 ),
           FILTER( COLUMN( history_earnings!1:1 ), history_earnings!1:1=A1 ),
           0
         )
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

you use ADDRESS that returns a string and then you join your two strings with a colon `:` but that is still a string not a valid range. try:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("history_earnings!"&
 ADDRESS(MATCH(B$2,  history_earnings!$A:$A, ),
         MATCH($A$1, history_earnings!$A$1:$Z$1, ))&":"&
 ADDRESS(MATCH(B$2,  history_earnings!$A:$A, ),
         MATCH($A$1, history_earnings!$A$1:$Z$1, )+11)))
```

[image]

also, in your question, you mention: `'sheetx!'!A1` which is also wrong due to two exclamation marks `!` correct being: `'sheetx'!A1` unless your sheet is called `sheetx!`